# Div with 100% width of screen, but inside a parent div with fixed width

Tags: css, html

I'm working on a project for a large webshop, but I've run into a problem.

I need to put a div with width: 100% of the screen, inside a div with a fixed width of 960px.

```
    <div> /* This div is fixed to 960px */
        <div> /* This is the div I want to fit the screen width */
        </div>
    </div>
```

Normally I would put the element outside my content area, e.g. in the wrapper or whereever I already have a div with 100% width. But that would involve changing a template which affects all of my clients webshops, and I only need it on this one.

So; basically - How do a set a div to be 100% width of the screen, inside a fixed width parent? Is it even possible?

Comment: Why don't you try to make de <div> entirely seperate of the page and float it somewhere using left: top:, I dont believe it is possible what you asked.

Answer (score 3):

If the fixed div has no "position:" style you could add `position: absolute; width: 100%;` to the inner div. I think the width percentage will then relate to the next parent that is positioned or the screen.

Comment: Ok, this will work but the inner div will be over the outter and will hide the elements placed after it.

Answer (score 0):

These divs are contained in a header with relative position which is moved by some jQuery to allow a banner to be revealed when hovering above a specific brand in the menu.

Using that method my div will relate to the div with relative pos, which is also 960px.

I'm starting to realize that my only option here probably is to go ahead and change the global template.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements with a width of 9999px, which you position to the left and right of the div.

See more here: https://css-tricks.com/examples/FullBrowserWidthBars/