# Full screen DIV inside a fix width DIV

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I read some questions like this but nothing can help me...

I have a bootstrap layout with fix (centered width margin: 0 auto) container width at 1170px.

Now in this content I need insert a div that respects the order of the divs (so no position: absolute), but has width 100%. In this way I can use this div to insert a banner with background-size: cover;

I read this [Div with 100% width of screen, but inside a parent div with fixed width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001653/div-with-100-width-of-screen-but-inside-a-parent-div-with-fixed-width)
this solution doesn't permit me to use a unique background image for the entere div..

I thing I can resolve it using a jquery that adds a negative margin-left and margin-right in base the distance between the centered div and the screen...

Can you help me ? ;)

Thanks

Comment: How about posting some of your code and what you have already tried.

Comment: Here the code. http://jsfiddle.net/xzt8vrfh/

Comment: Based on your code, I don't think what you are wanting to do it possible.  I would follow @Paulie_D suggestion.

Comment: yes the problem in that i can't alter the html structure because it's a drupal webside and i am not the webmaster... do you thing it's no possible with jquery too?

Comment: Any child element (no matter how its added via source or dynamically) can't be larger than it's parent unless its removed from the document flow.  You could possibly calculate where this child div is on the page via jQuery and then insert an absolutely positioned same height div on top of it (via z-index) that is full width. Or you could look at the drupal module and see if there is a way to update it to work the way you want.

Answer (score 4):

You are overthinking things.

You have a container div with a fixed width of 1170px..perhaps with a class of `.container` (not sure of Bootstrap). That doesn't mean you can't use the container class more than once.

So, just close the fixed width container before your full width div and reopen the container after it. Simple really.

```
<div class="container">

</div>

<div>
YOUR BANNER HERE
</div>

<div class="container">

</div>
```

Comment: I Paulie. I don't need an other container div. I nedd a div inside the container but with fullscreen width.

Comment: What's wrong with another container div?....That's the point....you can have more than one.

Comment: Yes Paulie but i dont need this. I need exactly this structure <div class="container"><div id="banner">I am a fullscreen div inside a 1170px container.</div></div>

Comment: You really don't...but if you find another way good luck with it.